# GNU GMP with Matlab and mex - Library Problems

Tags: c++, matlab, cygwin, mex, gmp

I am using Matlab (R2015a) together with Windows SDK 7.1 to compile a single C++ source file with Matlab's "mex" functionality. This works all fine. 
However, in this C++-file, I'd like to use the GNU GMP library (arbitrary precision arithmetic/bigint), since I would appreciate some big integer calculations.
Therefore, i downloaded gmp-6.0.0 and set up the Cygwin toolchain to compile my GMP libraries for my Win-7 (64-bit) machine.

I compile/configure GMP this way in Cygwin:

```
$ configure --host=none-pc-cygwin --enable-alloca=malloc-notreentrant  --enable-cxx --enable-static --disable-shared
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```

... which gives me the header- and library files without errors or problems (gmp.h, gmpxx.h) as well as the libraries (libgmp.a, libgmpxx.a).

In my C++-program, I include the header:

```
#include "gmpxx.h"
```

... and i copy the libraries/headers to the same matlab working directory. 
In my C++-code, I now try to use the GMP library, e.g. like this:

```
mpz_t val1;
mpz_init(val1);
```

I then call the matlab/mex/Windows SDK compiler (in Matlab) like so:

```
mex TestProgram.cpp -v libgmp.a libgmpxx.a
```

... which returns the following linker error:

```
Creating library TestProgram.lib and object TestProgram.exp
TestProgram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __gmpz_init referenced in function mexFunction
TestProgram.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

... And I do not know why it does this. Apparently, there are functions missing in the GMP library I compiled (?)... but why? Or is it a problem between mex and the windows SDK compiler?

Any suggestions of how to debug this? I already searched extensively, but the combination of mex and GMP is rarely used ==> little search results :-/

Edits:

- Do I have to supply/link an additional library/DLL since Cygwin is used to compile?
- Could it be a name mangling issue? (I also tried a purely C-based fuction/compilation, but with the exact same result)
- If I compile a dynamic library with Cygwin (and supply the DLLs to matlab), I get the same linker error

Best and many thanks!
Mario

Comment: Maybe try to spell it `-lgmpxx -lgmp`, potentially with an extra `-L/some/dir`, in case mex has trouble understanding things? Wait, does mex use gcc or does it use visual studio?

Comment: mex understands the library. (If I change the name, it doesn't find it anymore). Mex uses the windows compiler, not GCC. I am currently also trying with GCC, but it also does not (Yet) seem to work: The linker complains then:
libgmp.a(memory.o):memory.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `__getreent' 
libgmp.a(memory.o):memory.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `__getreent'

Comment: Update: I tried the whole story with msys2/mingw-w64 and using gnumex to force matlab to use the same GCC, with the result that the linker throws this error:
libgmp.a(memory.o):memory.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `__getreent' 
libgmp.a(memory.o):memory.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `__getreent'

Comment: Sounds like you compiled gmp with cygwin and tried to use it with mingw?